# TypeScript error on context value type mismatch

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am implementing React context using TypeScript and I seem to be getting and error on the `value` prop of my context.

Here is what the error says:

```
Type '{ createReferral: (referralData: { actionStepId: number; appTypeId: string; comment: string; createdDate: Date; createdBy: string; createdByDisplayName: string; currentAssigneeDisplayName: string; ... 4 more ...; submissionId: string; }) => void; getCurrentUser: () => AccountInfo; }' is not assignable to type 'SelectedContextType'.
```

So it looks like there is a mismatch between my expected context value types and the actual value types.

I declare my context as follows:

```
interface SelectedContextType {
  createReferral: (referralData: {
    actionStepId: number
    appTypeId: string
    comment: string
    createdDate: Date
    createdBy: string
    createdByDisplayName: string
    currentAssigneeDisplayName: string
    currentAssigneeGRNID: string
    reasonTypeId: number | string
    referralTypeId: number | string
    statusTypeId: number
    submissionId: string
  }) => void
  getCurrentUser: () => { name: string; username: string }
}

export const AppContext = createContext<SelectedContextType | undefined>(
  undefined
)
```

and I declare these functions in my context:

```
const AppProvider = ({ children, msalContext }: AppProps) => {
  function getCurrentUser() {
    return msalContext.accounts[0]
  }

  function createReferral(referralData: {
    actionStepId: number
    appTypeId: string
    comment: string
    createdDate: Date
    createdBy: string
    createdByDisplayName: string
    currentAssigneeDisplayName: string
    currentAssigneeGRNID: string
    reasonTypeId: number | string
    referralTypeId: number | string
    statusTypeId: number
    submissionId: string
  }) {
    referralAxios
      .post('/api/ReferralMasters', {
        actionStepID: referralData.actionStepId,
        appTypeID: referralData.appTypeId,
        comment: referralData.comment,
        createdDate: referralData.createdDate,
        createdBy: referralData.createdBy,
        createdByDisplayName: referralData.createdByDisplayName,
        currentAssigneeDisplayName: referralData.currentAssigneeDisplayName,
        currentAssigneeGRNID: referralData.currentAssigneeGRNID,
        reasonTypeID: referralData.reasonTypeId,
        referralTypeID: referralData.referralTypeId,
        statusTypeID: referralData.statusTypeId,
        submissionID: Number(referralData.submissionId),
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response)
        if (response.data.actionStepID === 2) {
          sendReferralEmail(response.data)
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error, 'testError')
      })
  }

  const appContext = { createReferral, getCurrentUser }
  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={appContext}>{children}</AppContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default withMsal(AppProvider)
```

I am not sure what exactly the error is saying. I see it referencing `AccountInfo` which does not exist as a type anywhere in my app.

The `msalContext.accounts[0]` is an object that looks like:

```
authorityType: "MSSTS"
environment: "login.windows.net"
homeAccountId: "89887r89e"
idTokenClaims: {aud: '1799}
localAccountId: "60000"
name: "User"
username: "User@STAR.COM"
```

example: [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDec1SoxIDCEAdsQB7wC+cAZlBCHAESHoxsBQoksXHACSAWQDOKADZlKSGtgDuwGAAsJ0uPSYs4AcgACKAF4BXQgHoQkqQFpOGPTz5yoDdEjgBBMGAAKzGDiuDxw+KrAUgAmhOQAXIioGAB0yFwAchBRSKFw1tKy1DAJYjaF8jA8tM7Aru5ongDKSFJIGEhR5TQAKgCeYJ44uWEEREjIDEhQUNIJABSEk9PSACIoMCgJQ2E7O1zAFI3EYMJRCeSmIABGU8O7cCi+fQOnCeIwULUA5ne7aCwgJCUN4fb6-HajdYdNbEBIwnL3CGcYhRABCvRBn3IP0RI2RHXRK2A4jAUhQvXSKEBmLBuPw5liMC84nEwC+5CQSCJJLJFKpSBp2PBIwZQKZLLZHKQAHEEOlhCtBTjcZxxBRnkhXnALtcpnAAD5wd5Y5WIxZTGZSDVanU3KAGo2goV097rUzia1nbWXO3Co2mK4gYmsiha420na0ACUcAAvAA+OAANwgwCidy+SBgJFFlAAquIpvMYwmhOR+UqANxwd1TcvUx0mrRVZzyATwf7kd7eXxdeCx-D4vsAHmarXanQoRQ1DtM5GyDFqHXjczuc4XS-TUecne7Pn8zCTab1A7meDQEWisWw+RkU4qWgS+4CECCJcT20Yc4wB3IcEz2a5jABZTHMMafiMFBqq0yRSBAXxzLefbJOg-xzjA4gANoAAwALrbrshAwOYf5IfeNAoWgaGUFheG5NUdwMN+MC-oOYwTBa0gLEgSyWjCmwhHS+yHMcNo+rcQlPP0mpeuGzq4v8ICAsCjYRoikIovCcJQn6GkEhiqnyep+Jor03KkuSlINnJpr3GgQHMqy7KcuZvJWQKhm2X8DkSs5MpygqSp+qq6rSWJur2oaNnBTxnFWmFXq2nqUVOl5OyusRHoJec4lQH64gBkGEqhrJqV3NGgm4hYFhwMkdXlc4fxQfAjxgH2cZCHpHHLFI2AATm0xiiB9rVGEREkXAq67MO+7IS+R7ZPaSbSKYSCxjgrV9rQ8Y4BekQxECtDDhYs3kTAyTzceUDxrk260EAA)

Comment: can you please send us the definition of `msalContext.accounts[0]` inside `AppProps`

Comment: Updated the question to include that content.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://tsplay.dev/NVeMZw

Comment: @ghybs added an example.

Comment: Make sure to put your [mcve] in the body of your question as well. Here you were missing AppProps and reference to MSAL library.

Answer (score 1):

[the AccountInfo.name value is nullable](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/e7a55511680aec602310f63db0bb5b7d2b07fab3/lib/msal-common/src/account/AccountInfo.ts#L20)

just make it nullable in your code too:

```
  getCurrentUser: () => { name?: string; username: string }
```